# Apple Developer Program Entity Difference

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, ionic-framework

I am using Mac OS X 10.11 and I am trying to debug build my app into iPhone 4 by running `sudo ionic run ios --device`. But it end up with the error saying `Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.`

After some searching, I found that I need to enroll to Apple Developer Program in order to have provisioning profiles. But during enrollment, I come across the entity option. The app I am going to build is going to be for company, but Apple require DUNS number. In order to get DUNS number, I need to wait for almost 2 weeks from dnb.com.

That's a long wait. So, I am thinking instead of choosing the company but choose the individual to open the account. Here I want to ask:

1. What is the difference between individual and company entity type of account? Is it fine for me to use individual instead of company so that no need to wait for 2 weeks?
2. Is it possible to debug build to device without Apple Developer Program account?

Comment: *In order to get DUNS number, I need to wait for almost 2 weeks from dnb.com* - Are you sure? Does the company not have an existing DUNS number? If they do, you should be able to just look it up right away.

Comment: @BSMP I never come across any DUNS number in Company registration before. Only see it with Apple thing. I guess maybe this is only in America law?